# Describe the integral solutions to $y^2 = 12x^3 - 39$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Does the above Diophantine equation have infinitely many integer solutions ? One such solution is $(x,y) = (4,27)$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can only find the solution you gave.

Comment: May I ask why you are interested in this particular equation?

Comment: So that you will be familiar with it, in general $y^2=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ will only have a ***finite*** number of integer points. See a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Integral_points) by Siegel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $144,$ you get a Mordell curve $U^2 = V^3 - 5616.$

This has only the solutions you knew about

```
E_-05616: r = 1   t = 1   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(48, 324)>
          R =   1.0595282130
           2 integral points
             1. (48, 324) = 1 * (48, 324)
             2. (48, -324) = -(48, 324)
```

http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL-